# Run a circle through the points of a quadric curve with JavaScript and Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, quadratic-curve

I want to run a circle through every point of a quadric curve because I'm making a circle-throw game.
This is an example code of my problem:

```js
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20,200,200,200);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.arc(20,20,20,Math.PI*2,0);
ctx.fill();
function loop(){
  //Code to move circle through the quadric curve
  //???
  //???
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
  ctx.arc(20,20,20,Math.PI*2,0);
  ctx.fill();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> Run that circle through the curve
```

How can I solve this?
Sorry for my English and thanks for the answers!

Comment: Hi, I found this tutorial that seems similar to what you want: http://www.html5code.nl/canvas-tutorial/tutorial-canvas-animation-movement-along-bezier-curve/

Comment: It's not quadratic Bézier curve, but thanks.

Comment: I said similar, not exact :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to code the parametric formula for the quadratic curve given below to get the points of the curve.

[image: quadratic Bezier formula]

This formula gives the points of the curve in terms of three other points and `t`.

The first point is where the path begins before the call to `quadraticCurveTo`, the other two points are the points passed to `quadraticCurveTo`.

You change the value of `t` to get different points of the curve, when `t` is `0` you get the first point and when `t` is `1` you get the last point, values between `0` and `1` are going to give you points in the middle of the curve.

You can also get the points of the curve by drawing the curve using `quadraticCurveTo` and check the colours of the pixels with `getImageData`.